# Unpopular/Obscure solvers/algorithms that you used

Tags: solver

There are many (numeric) optimizers which solve some subset of the set of *multi-objective, black-or-grey-or-white box, robust, stochastic, mixed-integer, non-linear, non-smooth, manifold-constrained programming* problems.

Some of them are well known. Such as all the solvers that appear in the Mittelmann benchmarks. I don't want to hear about those, I want to hear about obscure, old, bleeding edge, unknown solvers or algorithms that you chose over the more popular well known ones:

**What made you choose it over more well known solvers?**

**Where can I learn more about it?**

**What is the underlying principle?**

**What kind of problems can it solve?**

**Under what license/pricing is it (or an implementation of it) available for hobbyist, academics or professionals?**

**From what programming languages can it (or an implementation of it) be called?**

When describing an algorithm please be specific (not just "evolutionary algorithm") about it.

*Background*

If I find any solver/algorithms intriguing I might decide to wrap/implement them for a modeling language. Others might find a solver that fits their use case in the replies or learn something new and interesting.